# How do I use dense optical flow to filter the key points given by SIFT?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, sift, opticalflow

I have a video, and I have applied SIFT and dense optical flow (Farneback) to it (Using python, and open CV). Is there a way to filter the key points given by sift using the dense optical flow, so that I only get the key points of the MOVING objects and it ignores those in the background?

Any help is much appreciated :)

I tried to filter it based on the "projected point" in the next frame, but I was unable to get it to work. At one point I was getting 2 points in the WHOLE video in just random places. I am not sure what I am doing wrong

EDIT --------------

I figured out that the output of the dense optical flow return the "shift" in x and y of every single pixel co-ordinate. I also figured out how to separate the keypoints returned by SIFT by x,y pixel co-ordinate, though I did need to round down or up to turn it into an Int value.

I now need to figure out how the optical flow algorithm decides which points to "color", and then use those co-ordinates to filter the key points. Any ideas?

Comment: You know where your keypoints are, so just test those positions in your flow map.

Comment: Right conceptually I know that's what im supposed to do, but I don't know HOW and I can't find any information on the internet... I feel like there might be this SPECIFIC point that I am failing to understand... could you maybe show me an example? or link a webpage that does? Thank you!

Comment: If I remember it right, the flow map has x and y coordinates and their elements are 2D vectors (2 float values?) which tell you where you have to go from that pixel coordinates to.

Comment: This was super helpful, could you please check the edit too?

Comment: Please don't use "EDIT:".  Don't ask one question, then append stuff to ask a different question.  Instead, figure out one single question that you want to ask, and revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time and asks that one question.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how the optical flow algorithm decides which points to "color"".